# When user login again then data was removed from Firebase database Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a database which stores user information like email, password, latitude, longitude and plant location. `plant location` is that when user click on map then latitude and longitude of that location is saved in plant location.

Database Image Before:
[image]

But when I signout the current user and then login back again with the same email then plant location was removed. As you can now plant location and its child got deleted.

Database After :

[image]

Help me please with this.

MapsActivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        AppCompatCallback {
    private static final String Tag = "MapsActivity";
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GeoFire geoFire;
    SharedPrefrence mShared;
    public AppCompatDelegate delegate;
    private final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    public Boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUESTCODE = 1234;
    public static DatabaseReference mReference,user_ref;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    Toolbar tool;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ImageView img;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    String userID;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        delegate = AppCompatDelegate.create(this, this);
        delegate.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        delegate.setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        getlocationpermission();
        mShared=new SharedPrefrence(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        img = findViewById(R.id.tree_button);
        mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserData");
        user_ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("You");
        tool = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        delegate.setSupportActionBar(tool);
        delegate.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);//use for toggling navbar
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);    
        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged Out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Login.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };
       geoFire = new GeoFire(user_ref);
    }


    void initMap() {
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
    }

    private void getlocationpermission() {
        String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                initMap();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUESTCODE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUESTCODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocationMethod() {
        Log.d(Tag, "getting the device location");
        FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        final Task<Location> location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Location currentlocation = task.getResult();
                    User_Data user_data=new User_Data(mShared.getUser_pass(),mShared.getUser_email(),currentlocation.getLatitude(),
                            currentlocation.getLongitude());
                  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentlocation.getLatitude(),
                  currentlocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                  DatabaseReference user=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserData");
                  user.child(userID).setValue(user_data);
                  addMarker(new LatLng(currentlocation.getLatitude(), currentlocation.getLongitude()), mMap);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Error while finding the location" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        getDeviceLocationMethod();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        location_to_firebase(googleMap);
    }

    private void location_to_firebase(final GoogleMap google_map) {
        int height = 150;
        int width = 150;
        final BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        Bitmap b = bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        final Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
        google_map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                Marker marker = google_map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromBitmap(smallMarker));
                final LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
                final DatabaseReference newPost = mReference.child(userID);
                newPost.child("plant location").push().setValue(latLng);
            }
        });
        mReference.child(userID).child("plant location").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot s:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    final LatLng lng = new LatLng(s.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class),
                            s.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class));
                    google_map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
                            position(lng).title(s.getKey())).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(smallMarker));
                    google_map.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(lng).radius(500).strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Login.java

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText _email, _password;
    Button _submit,_signup;
    SharedPrefrence mShared;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUESTCODE=1234;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        _email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        _password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        _submit = findViewById(R.id.login);
        _signup=findViewById(R.id.signup);
        mShared=new SharedPrefrence(this);
        _signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,Signup.class));
            }
        });
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        _submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSignin();
            }
        });
        runtimepermission();
    }


    private void startSignin() {
        final String email = _email.getText().toString();
        final String pass = _password.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "SigninProblem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mShared.saveEmail(Login.this,email);
                        mShared.savePass(Login.this,pass);
                        Intent i=new Intent(Login.this,MapsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }

                }
            }).addOnCanceledListener(new OnCanceledListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCanceled() {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your login method ?

Comment: I don't think there is anything in Login class still I have edited it.

Comment: are you doing something to the database when you logout ?

Comment: No..It just happen to that plant location child I don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when I signout the current user and then login back again with the same email then plant location was removed.

The problem isn't happening when you login back is happening everytime your map is ready. You are calling `getDeviceLocationMethod()` right in your `onMapReady()` method which means that everytime your map is ready, you are creating a new `User_Data` object, meaning that you are overriding the existing user from the database. That's way all the data within `plant location` node is deleted. To solve this, simply chech if the user already exist. If it doesn't, add it to the database otherwise take no action.